# Long running requests with gunicorn + nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I've put together an integration server for our Django-powered application. A few of the features are still experimental, and result in overly long requests.

I'm okay with the poor performance, for now, but I need to be able to integrate. Whenever we use the feature that leads to a long request, the app hangs (as expected) and then, after maybe a minute and a half, returns a '502 - Bad Gateway'. The rest of the app works fine.

I checked the gunicorn log, and whenever this happens I get a line like

```
2012-01-20 17:30:13 [23128] [DEBUG] GET /results/
2012-01-20 17:30:43 [23125] [ERROR] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/demo/python_envs/frontend/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 111, in run
    os.setpgrp()
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

however, this happens long before the actual worker timeout, which I've set to 10 minutes just to make sure. Here's part of the upstart script that runs gunicorn.

```
description "..."

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
#Send KILL after 5 seconds
kill timeout 5
respawn

env VENV="/path/to/a/virtual/env/"

#how to know the pid
pid file $VENV/run/guniconr-8080.pid

script
exec sudo -u demo $VENV/bin/gunicorn_django --preload --daemon -w 4 -t 600 --log-level debug --log-file $VENV/run/gunicorn-8080.log -p $VENV/run/gunicorn-8080.pid -b localhost:8080 /path/to/settings.py
end script
```

I'm running gunicorn version 0.13.4. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is a [cross-post from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/352123/long-running-requests-with-gunicorn-nginx).

Answer (score 4):

Are you connecting directly to gunicorn? Or is there an ngnix or so in between? There are some 90 second timeouts in nginx if I recall correctly.

As an aside, for such ill-performing requests, there are generally two solutions:

- Cache the result and get a cron job to call a custom django management command that does the calculation and fills the cache.
- An asynchronous task queue like celery does the actual calculation and you do a separate request to check if it's ready.

Comment: As the title suggests, I'm using nginx. I've set the timeout to 10 minutes for testing, but it times out earlier (longer, however, than 90 seconds).

Comment: Disregard that, maybe it's not longer than 90 seconds... do you have a reference for where you got that number?

Comment: ...also- I understand how to deal with long-running requests in the general case. This is an in-development feature that I need to be able to deploy, with poor performance, to our integration server- on better hardware and after further development, the request isn't ridiculously long-running.

Comment: I checked, the default for nginx is apparently 60 seconds. Gunicorn 30. (90 was what I set gunicorn's to, see http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/11/24/apache-nginx-gunicorn-timeout.html )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Asynchronous workers](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#worker-class) in Gunicorn?

Especially good for slow requests et al..

Comment: No, but I'm pretty sure the problem was misconfiguration. Since then, we've taken care of our performance issues, so I never had to fully solve this. There are a number of reasons I can't use async Gunicorn workers right now, though they may be an option in the future.